# How to create ImageView with TRUNCATED text overlay

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, overlay, android-imageview

I have a display that is in gridview. And I am keen to know how to have truncated text overlay that will fit within the image view.

I have included code for the gridview and the imageview:

Main XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Home -- "
        android:typeface="serif" />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Exhibition "
        android:typeface="serif" />

</LinearLayout>


 <FrameLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

     <GridView
         android:id="@+id/grid_view"
         style="@style/PhotoGrid"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:background="#000000"
         android:padding="4dp"
         android:columnWidth="@dimen/photo_size"
         android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/photo_spacing"
         android:numColumns="2"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:scrollbars="none"
         android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
         android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/photo_spacing" >

    </GridView>

</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Image view and text view XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true" />

         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/recipename"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                 android:textSize="15sp"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:typeface="serif"
                 android:textColor="#F3F781" />

             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chefname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textColor="#F3F781"  />

              <TextView
                android:id="@+id/adddate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textColor="#F3F781"  />
         </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recipename"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textColor="#F3F781"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:text="testtestttest" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chefname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#F3F781"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:text="test1test1test1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/adddate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#F3F781"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:text="12/12/2014" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

hope it will help you